# RabbitMQ PrefTest using SSL

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, performance-testing

I am trying to use PrefTest for RabbitMQ (https://www.rabbitmq.com/java-tools.html) for testing RabbitMQ performance. RabbitMQ is SSL secured and running on port 5672 and when running PrefTest:

```
bash-4.3# runjava com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest -h    amqps://preftest:preftest@messagebus.default.svc.cluster.local:5672 -x 1 -y 2 -u "throughput-test-1" -a --id “test 1”
id: “test, starting consumer #0
Main thread caught exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:50)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:60)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:900)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:859)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:817)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:954)
        at com.rabbitmq.perf.MulticastSet.run(MulticastSet.java:81)
        at com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest.main(PerfTest.java:134)
```

Comment: It's called a "Perf" test, not a "Pref" test. Maybe your username/password is wrong? A connection timeout implies that your MQ server is not responding. It could be due to incorrect connection properties, bad network connection, conflicting firewall rules, etc.

Comment: Hi James - sorry mispelled Pref.
Looking on the RabbitMQ admin - i can see the user and it has permission for vhost / 
I have exposed the RabbitMQ admin kubernetes service, and i can do curl -k to it. So connection working (also tried nslookup which returned the ip).